# Swift: Enum case is not a member of type 'String' force to use raw value

Tags: swift, enums

I have string enum:

```
enum Country:String {
    case France
    case Germany
    case UnitedStates
}
```

But depending on the uibutton restorationIdentifier I want to do something.

I have this ibaction:

```
@IBAction func countrySelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let selection:String = sender.restorationIdentifier else { return}
    switch selection {
    case Country.France:

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error on this line:

`Enum case 'France' is not a member of type 'String'`

line of code:

`case Country.France:`

I can fix the error changing that line to:

`case Country.France.rawValue`

But my question is, why do I need to or force to use the raw value?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to compare a `String` to a `Country` value.  They're not the same type.  As you noted, you could change your `switch` `cases` to `String`: `Country.France.rawValue`.

Or you can convert the `String` into a `Country` value:

```
@IBAction func countrySelection(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let selection = sender.restorationIdentifier else { return }
    guard let country = Country(rawValue: selection)

    switch country {
    case .France:
        // handle France
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Note:  That isn't really what the *restorationIdentifier* is for.

Comment: I don't want to use tags for the buttons. But there is another way to set an ID other they set the `restorationIdentifier `?

Comment: Using the `tag` is the approved way to do it. You could make your enum `Int` based and use the tag value.

Comment: Some folks use the current string of the button, but that is not a good practice since your app might be localized which would change the button text.